# Set validation dependent on other fields

Tags: c#, knockout.js

I have a field called ReclaimTotalAmount that displays a value from a c# model.

```
<div class="container-left">
Reclaim Total: <span data-bind='text: model.ReclaimTotalAmount'></span>
</div>
```

And I also have a field that displays the value of the Sum of fields:

```
 <div class="container-left">
    Countered Total:<span data-bind='text: model.CounteredTotalAmount'></span>
</div>
```

To get the CounteredTotalAmount I use the following

```
self.model.CounteredTotalAmount = ko.computed(function () {
    var SumCounterTotals = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < self.model.CounterReclaimViewModels().length; i++) {
        SumCounterTotals += (
           parseFloat(self.model.CounterReclaimViewModels()[i].CounteredTimeAmount())
         + parseFloat(self.model.CounterReclaimViewModels()[i].CounteredMileAmount())
         + parseFloat(self.model.CounterReclaimViewModels()[i].CounteredAppurtenanceAmount())
     )
    }
```

So I need to check weather the Countered total is greater than the ReclaimTotal. I tried this:
I created an extension

```
 self.model.CounteredTotalAmount.extend({
    greaterThan: { params: self.model.ReclaimTotalAmount, message: "Car number high must be greater than the low." }
});
```

then this is the function

```
 ko.validation.rules['greaterThan'] = {
    validator: function (val, other) {
        if (val != null && val != "" && other != null) {
            var first = parseInt(val);
            var second = parseInt(ko.unwrap(other));
            if (!isNaN(first) && !isNaN(second)) {
                return first > second;
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
    message: 'Must be greater than or equal to the other value'
};
```

everything works except the validation. I am not able to generate an error message if the Countered Total is greater than the Reclaim total...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple things could go wrong, but because you haven't' posted a complete example only code fragments you need to check the following things:

1. Because you are creating a custom validator you need to call `ko.validation.registerExtenders();` before you want to use it for the first time.
2. the KO `.extend({ })` returns the extended observable so you need to override the existing property with the result:

   ```
   self.CounteredTotalAmount = self.CounteredTotalAmount.extend({
       greaterThan: {
          params: self.ReclaimTotalAmount,
          message: "Car number high must be greater than the low."
       }
   });
   ```
3. Because KO validation only overrides the `value` and `checked` binding to automatically display the error message. So you need to use the `validationMessage` binding to display your error because you are using the `text` binding here:

   ```
   <div class="container-left">
        Countered Total:<span data-bind='text: CounteredTotalAmount'></span>
        <span data-bind="validationMessage: CounteredTotalAmount"></span>
   </div>
   ```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTvMH/) with the simplified version of your code.

Comment: Thanks - Its working now, I think my main issue was that I did not have the ko.validation.registerExtenders(); call after the extended function...